# VBScript runs twice, once when page loads and once on submit. Only need on submit?

Tags: vb.net, asp-classic, vbscript

I feel like I'm missing something here.. I've added a few different things to the vbscript to try and make it only run when the submit button was click rather than twice (the second the page loads and then on submit), but it either broke it or didn't work. Any help for this beginner programmer would be greatly appreciated. If you need the html, let me know. Edit: Still looking for help! :(

```
<% Sub sendEmail(mailFrom, mailTo, mailSubject, mailMessage, mailServer, mailUsername, mailPassword)
Set MyMail = CreateObject("cdo.message")
MyMail.From = mailFrom
MyMail.To = mailTo
MyMail.Subject = mailSubject
MyMail.HTMLBody = mailMessage
MyMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
MyMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = mailServer
MyMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = mailUsername
MyMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = mailPassword
MyMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
MyMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
MyMail.Configuration.Fields.Update
MyMail.Send
Set MyMail = nothing
End Sub

Dim mailFrom, mailTo, mailSubject, mailMessage, mailServer, mailUsername, mailPassword

mailFrom = Request.form(example)
mailTo = "example"
mailSubject = "example"
mailMessage = "example"
mailServer = "example"
mailUsername = "example"
mailPassword = "example"

Call sendEmail(mailFrom, mailTo, mailSubject, mailMessage, mailServer, mailUsername, mailPassword)
%>
```

Answer (score 1):

If `Request.form(example) = ""` then either the page is not the result of a form submission (or the form was submitted without this data) so;

```
if Request.form(example) <> "" then
   'is a form submission
   .. email code
end if
```

If you want to more accurately discriminate a submit add a constant hidden field to the form

```
<input type="hidden" name="sendemail" value="1" />
```

and look for `Request.form("sendemail") = "1"`.

Comment: I've tried adding that before and it didn't seem to work. I put if request.form(email) = "" then else 'vbscript code' end if ? Was that wrong?

Comment: did you quote the name? `request.form("email")`? if so you would need to edit you question with the code+html

Comment: When I do that (hidden field), everything runs fine, I just never receive the email, probably not sending it.